# What are the "units" and "non-trivial divisors of zero" in a ring?

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, divisibility

I'm confused on what units and non-trivial divisors of zero are when it comes to rings. For example, say I have this finite ring: R=GF(2)[x] mod x^3 + 1 = 0.

Now I know the elements are 0, 1, x, x + 1, x^2, x^2 + 1, x^2 + x, and x^2 + x + 1.
Aren't those all non-trivial divisors of zero besides 1?
And for the units, I read a unit of a ring is one of those elements, we'll say 'e', such that there exists the inverse of 'e' where e * e^-1 = 1. Do I multiply each of these elements by its inverse to find the units?

Also, does it matter if we can't obtain a field or not to find these two things? I know the example above doesn't give a field, but something like x^3 + x + 1, which has the same elements, does give a field.

Comment: The two rings $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^3+1)$ and $\Bbb F_2[x]/(x^3+x+1$ *do not have the same elements*, because their elements are equivalence classes with respect to different equivalence relations.

Comment: Hmm, what elements would be different in the x^3 + x + 1??

Comment: They’re all different. Zero in the one is the set of polynomials divisible by $x^3+1$, while zero in the other is the set of polynomials divisible by $x^3+x+1$. You will be begging for trouble if you think that the sets are the same just because they are represented by the same polynomials of degree less than $3$.

Comment: Oh no I didn't think the sets were the same, but that, like you said, they are represented by the same polynomials. Like when I set up an addition/multiplication table, I have the same polynomials written down.

Comment: Right you are, then. Keep it up.

Answer (score 1):

A *unit* in a ring is an element which has an inverse (i.e., an $a$ such that there is $b$ such that $a \cdot b = 1$). A *zero divisor* is an element $a \ne 0$ such that there is a $b \ne 0$ with $a \cdot b = 0$ (here I use the names $1$ for the multiplicative identity and $0$ for the additive one).

The elements of your ring are rather few; you can work out the full multiplication table and check for the above. Bonus is that your ring is commutative, as is easy to prove.

Comment: Oh I have the addition and multiplication tables written out already. So I'm looking for the row/column intersection where there's a 1 for the units?

Comment: The units are the elements whose row contains a $1$; the zero-divisors are the elements whose row contains a $0$ (other than in the column headed by zero, of course).

Comment: Okay that makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In a field, all elements other than $0$ are units, and there are no nontrivial zero-divisors.  In a finite ring (with 1), any non-unit is a zero-divisor.  That's not true in general for infinite rings.

Comment: Wait, so if all my units besides 0 are the elements, then there's no non-trivial zero divisors?

Comment: Well, since your polynomial $x^3+1$ is not irreducible, there are going to be zero-divisors in the factor ring.

Comment: Do you mean "if all elements other than $0$ are units, ..."?  Since a unit can't be a zero-divisor, that would indeed imply there are no non-trivial zero-divisors.  But that's not the case here: as @Lubin mentioned, $x^3 + 1$ is not irreducible, and a factor of $x^3+1$ is a zero-divisor in your ring.